# RegEx with Back Reference-Unix

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I am executing below commands on Bourne shell but getting some unexpected error.

```
$ echo abcd 123 | grep --color '[a-z]*'

Output(abcd is colored) : abcd 123

$ echo abcd 123 | sed 's/\([a-z]*\)/\1/'

Output : abcd 123
```

shouldn't the result of  2nd command be **abcd** only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `\([a-z]*\)` captures the `abcd` part and the `\1` backreference reinserts it back.

To remove the rest of the string use `.*` after the capturing group:

```
echo abcd 123 | sed 's/\([a-z]*\).*/\1/'
```

If the letters come at the beginning of the string, add a `^` at the pattern start.

Here is a [Bash Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/vJw6N0)

Comment: Thank you , i just understood :)